# Formatting a diagram's x-Axis in MS Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

In Microsoft Excel 2013, I created the following diagram:

[image]

As you can see from the axis, the framerates (y-axis) have been measured at an arbitrary element count. The values of the x-axis are chaotic.

The above diagram has two problems:

- Excel does not consider the x-axis' actual value. The horizontal space between 100 and 3600 is the same as the space between 2.3 million and 20 million
- The printed numbers are directly used from the input data set. I would prefer to have nicely formated, major numbers like "1000, 2000, 3000, ..." instead of the above numbers.

How is this possible with Microsoft Excel? (Or do you recomment using another application?)

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution: Instead of using a standard line chart, you need to select the **xy-chart**.

Result: 
[image]